# encoding dataframe in pyspark to 0 and 1

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to find specific words of a column in pyspark data frame with multiple conditions and create a separate column as "label". If the words in the "body" column match with the lists (cat and dog) the '0' and '1' labels will be created. Here is the code below:

```
dog_list = ['my dog', 'I have a dog', 'my puppy', 'dog', 'my pup']
cat_list = ['my cat','I have a cat','my kitty', 'my pussy', 'cat']

df2 = df2.withColumn("label", ( 
                              when( col("body").like(('% + i + %') for i in dog_list), 1 )
                              .when( col("body").like(('% + i + %') for i in cat_list), 0 )
                              .otherwise(0) 
                              )
                    )
```

but I get this error message:

```
      4 df2 = df2.withColumn("label", ( 
----> 5                               when( col("body").like(('% + i + %') for i in dog_list), 1 )
      6                               .when( col("body").like(('% + i + %') for i in cat_list), 0 )
      7                               .otherwise(0)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use a regex match

```py
dogs = '|'.join(dog_list)
col("body").rlike(f'% + {dogs} + %')
```

Comment: Thanks, Leo for your comments. I revised the code as:

'''
dogs = '|'.join(dog_list)
cats = '|'.join(cat_list)
df2 = df2.withColumn("label", 
                     ( 
                       when( col("body").rlike(f'% + {dogs} + %'), 1 )
                      .when( col("body").rlike(f'% + {dogs} + %'), 0 )
                      .otherwise(0))
                     )
'''
but still, I get the same error message.

Comment: I am not sure you can do when twice and I bet the error comes from there. Can you do something like when(...).otherwise(when(...).otherwise(...))?

Comment: The code works.  You are correct, there was a typo in my last message which the second "dog" term must be "cat"